# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource: - The resource was not found

Tags: r, ssh, gcloud

I'm trying to run R on Google Cloud following Google's suggested [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-r-at-scale#make_sure_you_have_ssh_keys). However, I have experienced some trouble when finally creating the cluster. When creating the cluster with

```
elasticluster start myslurmcluster
```

I get the following error message

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/MY_PROJECT/zones/us-central1-b/instances/myslurmcluster-frontend001' was not found`

I had run through previous stages of the tutorial several times with no problems but I suspect the issue might be related to the SSH keys so that I can sign in to my cluster.

Any help or advice greatly received!

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it, so it gains greater visibility for other community users? Thanks @MauOlivares

Comment: Thanks for you help @sllopis , I have not accepted it yet because I still get the same error, but I want to fully understand the issue before commenting on it or following. In the meantime I upvoted it.

Comment: I have followed the tutorial from A to Z and worked for me, but I would note a few things on the tutorial itself:
1-It is recommended not to use the Cloud Shell for this.
2-The config file will be created in `./elasticluster` every time you run `elasticluster start myslurmcluster` unless you already have it in that location, which is not created itself until that command is run for 1st time.
3-If you have run `gcloud compute config-ssh`, try deleting the files `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` and `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine{.pub}` and run it again.
Let's see if some of this works for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/MY_PROJECT/zones/us-central1-b/instances/myslurmcluster-frontend001' was not found
```

> The error you are getting means that when you are trying to compute SSH, your resource was not found. The reason for this case is the instance zone and gcloud default zone are different. The command line didn’t specified the instance zone. So the google cloud compute default zone was used. Obviously, The instance should not be found in the default zone. Just adding the zone option in command could solve the **[problem](https://deeperf.com/2019/05/14/Troubleshooting-gcloud-compute-ssh-could-not-fetch-instance/)**. The command format is like:

```
gcloud compute --project "MY_PROJECT" ssh --zone "us-central1-b" "myslurmcluster-frontend001"
```

To see what your default region and zone settings are, run the following gcloud **[command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region#looking_up_the_default_zone_or_region)**:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project [PROJECT_ID]
```

where `[PROJECT_ID]` is your own project ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps... Easy way to find out instance zones without having to type/know instance name.

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

Should list instances and information - including (time)ZONE.